# File Input field sencha touch does not show phone memory browse option in android 4.1.2

Tags: android, file-upload, sencha-touch-2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using sencha touch to write a hybrid app for android. I have a screen wherein user can upload a file from their device. I am using sencha touch's filefield to open the file browser for user. Below is the code for the view

```
Ext.define('BikeApp.view.FileUploadView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'fileuploadview',
    requires: [
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.field.File'
    ],
    config: {
        title: 'Upload file',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'My Uploader',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'filefield',
                itemId: 'fileField',
                label: "Select file:"
                    //name: 'photo',
                    //accept: 'image'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Submit',
                itemId: 'uploadSubmit',
                margin: '1em 0 0 0'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

The issue i am facing is that on one of the android devices (Samsung Galaxy Chat) which runs on android 4.1.2 the options shown to user when he taps on browse do not include an option where user can browse his phone memory or sd card (whatever is available) and select a file. The only options shown are Music files, Gallery and Music Player. I have attached a screenshot below showing these options. I have a file stored in phone's internal memory and i cannot browse that path and select it from these options.

[image]

What's interesting is that this thing works correctly on android 5.0 and i get all the options. Any help ?